# Flash scope not working in glassfish with jsf2.1

Tags: jsf, glassfish

When I am using flash scope in glassfish it lives longer than one request but works fine with jetty8 and even tried the latest version of glassfish but its not working. The JSF has a jira about it and they have solved it in the next version, I have even tried that version of jars for JSF but still same problem persists in Glassfish but works fine for Jetty8. Facing this problem from many days can anyone throw some light on this??

Answer (score 2):

Jetty as being a barebones servletcontainer doesn't come with any JSF implementation bundled and the one supplied along with the webapp will always be used.

Glassfish as being a fullfledged Java EE applicationserver comes with a JSF implementation bundled and the one supplied along with the webapp will by default always be ignored. If you'd like to upgrade the Glassfish-bundled JSF implementation, then you should be replacing the JAR in `/glassfish/modules` folder. Or, if you'd like to force Glassfish to use the webapp-supplied JSF implementation, then you should add the following entries to `/WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml` (or `sun-web.xml`, depending on GF version used):

```xml
<class-loader delegate="false" />
<property name="useBundledJsf" value="true" />
```

Comment: Hi BalusC thanks for your answer, but I have already added these two lines in my sun-web.xml in my project, and even tried after changing the jars in glassfish/modules, but still it remains the same. my jsf version is 2.1.2.

Comment: 2.1.2? The most Flash scope related problems were fixed in Mojarra 2.1.7.

Comment: Sorry BalusC but I have tried that version of JSF too, but same problem. :(

Comment: I have the same problem: Glassfish 3.1.2.2. Substituted the bundled JSF implementation with Mojarra 2.1.11.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem was caused by Mojarra (even 2.1.11) not able to cope with HTTP chunking. By disabling it the flash was emptied as expected.

You can disable it in the admin console

- Configurations
- server-config
- Network Config
- Protocols
- http-listener-[N]

  - HTTP tab
  - Chunking